# Use of !If intrinsic function in a SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I thought you could do something like this for a state machine using SAM:

```
SM:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${StageName}-State-Machine"
      DefinitionUri: statemachine/dddd.asl.json
      Events:
        Schedule:
          !If
            - IsPrimaryRegion
            -
              Type: Schedule
              Properties:
                Description: Schedule to run the twilio number state machine
                Enabled: !Ref ScheduleEnabled
                Schedule: "rate(1 hour)"
            - 
              Type: Schedule
              Properties:
                Description: Schedule to run the twilio number state machine
                Enabled: !Ref ScheduleEnabled
                Schedule: "rate(1 hour)"
```

But SAM validation fails for this. It also fails if I use State instead of Enabled in properties. Ultimately I want to have a way to set Enabled dynamically, using a parameter or any other way. But validation with State fails.

Also tried this:

```
Enabled: !If [IsPrimaryRegion, true, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define [Conditions block](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html), then you can use these conditions in  your template like below:

```
Parameters:
  PrimaryRegion:
    Type: String
    Description: Primary region

Conditions:
  IsPrimaryRegion: !Equals [ !Ref PrimaryRegion, !Ref "AWS::Region" ]

Resources:
  SM:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
      Properties:
        Name: !Sub "${StageName}-State-Machine"
        DefinitionUri: statemachine/dddd.asl.json
        Events:
          Schedule:
            Type: Schedule
            Properties:
              Description: Schedule to run the twilio number state machine
              Enabled: !If [ IsPrimaryRegion, true, false ]
              Schedule: "rate(1 hour)"
```

Eventually:

```
Parameters:
  PrimaryRegion:
    Type: String
    Description: Primary region

Conditions:
  IsPrimaryRegion: !Equals [ !Ref PrimaryRegion, !Ref "AWS::Region" ]
  IsNotPrimaryRegion: !Not [ !Equals [ !Ref PrimaryRegion, !Ref "AWS::Region" ] ]

Resources:
  SMPrimary:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
      Condition: IsPrimaryRegion
      Properties:
        Name: !Sub "${StageName}-State-Machine"
        ...
              Enabled: true
  SM:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
      Condition: IsNotPrimaryRegion
      Properties:
        Name: !Sub "${StageName}-State-Machine"
        ...
              Enabled: false
```

Comment: I am aware of Conditions, but I do not want to use them in this case. With conditions you'll have to duplicate things and I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: I paste here two variants - second with duplicate, and first without... what you meaning?

Comment: You have 2 of these `Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine` and that's what I am trying to avoid. I want just one state machine listed in my template

Comment: The 1st solution contains only one state machine...

Comment: Have you tried running this? This will fail. I am talking about the first example.

Comment: Meaning about running the exact code that I provide here?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you run this, I am sure this will fail